# Pyinstaller to package app hidden-import warning/exceptions

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So, I've had some trouble setting up my application through Inno setup Compiler, at first I assumed it was a problem within Inno itself but on further inspection I think it is my actual exe. I am able to create a working exe file that runs my program properly but only on my own pc. I am able to create the setup file that also works through Inno setup but it only works on my own pc. I have sent both the actual exe file and the Inno setup file to another computer and downloaded it there and ran it, both meet the same `"Fatal Error: failed to run script tk_app.py"`. Therefore, the problem must be that I have not been able to pavkage the app properly with pyinstaller.

My prgoram has 5 files in total (all in the same folder): `main.py, file1.py, file2.py file3.py, tk_app.py`

All of them importing each other and using python libraries. I know that pyinstaller supports librarires such as pandas, tkinter and many more without needing the `--hidden-impoort=` command and that it will pick up all files within the program if there are files that are importing each other.

So I use the file `tk_app.py` (which contains my tkinter UI and imports `main.py` which then goes onto import `file1.py` which import another file so on)

The pyinstaller command line I use to make the exe is as follows:

`PS C:\Users\ripta\Desktop\CODING\CSV_Upload> pyinstaller -w --hidden-import=bs4 --hidden-import=fake_useragent --hidden-import=urllib.prase --hidden-import=urllib.request --hidden-import=os --hidden-import=pandas.io.parsers --icon=trademark_icon.ico --onefile  tk_app.py`

My question is, will pyinstaller tell me when it needs a given `--hidden-import='name'` when running becuase it doesn not throw up any errors and does produce a `spec file`, a `build folder` and a `dist folder` containing the exe file.

I have noticed that it throws up WARNINGs or Exceptions (also not sure why it mentions django as I do not import or use it at all inthe application) :

`59182 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-django.db.backends.py' from 'c:\\users\\ripta\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'... 61711 WARNING: Hidden import "django.db.backends.__pycache__.base" not found! 61712 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-django.py' from 'c:\\users\\ripta\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'... Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 21, in walk_packages File "c:\users\ripta\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>`

Or show Hidden-import not found (Of imports I have no idea about):

`149329 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found! 149330 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!`

The fact that the script fails to run on any other computer besided my own leads me to think that it must be lacking a dependency that is only found on my computer, therefore I am not using pyinstaller correctly but am not too sure where exactly I am making the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First I've uninstalled Setuptools and reinstalled it with specific version. Then, I've imported *pkg_resources.py2_warn* as hidden import :

```
pip uninstalled setuptools
pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<45.0.0'
pyinstaller --hidden-import='pkg_resources.py2_warn' tk_app.py
```

It worked for me.